# Компиляция программы с другими значениями переменных

Tags: c++, c

Уже задавал похожий вопрос, но возникла надобность передать строку в программу на стадии компиляции.

Есть код:

```
#ifdef VALUE
    std::cout << VALUE << std::endl;
#endif // VALUE
#ifndef VALUE
    char* VALUE = "not defined";
    std::cout << VALUE << std::endl;
#endif // !VALUE
```

При компиляции с параметром

```
cl /DVALUE=100 core.cpp
```

Всё работает и программа выдаёт число.Как я понял, ключ /D - это вариант только для чисел, а есть ли аналогичный ключ для строк?

Comment: А если попробовать так `cl /DVALUE="some text" core.cpp`?

Comment: @Majestio не компилируется , ибо пытается "some text" - необъявленный идентификатор... в одиночных кавычках компилируется, но передаётся что-то не то...

Comment: у меня на линуксе работает `-DVALUE='"a b"'` `g++ 1.cpp -DVALUE='"a b"' -o 1`

Comment: @pavel под виндой не получается, способ Harry работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не для чисел, а для литералов. Просто в тексте `VALUE` до компиляции будет заменено на то, что вы подставите.

Хотите с кавычками - подставьте в командной строке Windows

```
 cl /DVALUE=\"100\"
```

А вообще - читайте о препроцессоре, это большая и интересная тема... Например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y4skk93w.aspx).

Comment: Благодарю. И за ссылку отдельное спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Строка компиляции для `clang` (FreeBSD):

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -DVALUE='"Some text"' Hello.cpp -o Hello
```

Сам тестовый код:

```
#ifndef VALUE
#define VALUE "Test"
#endif

int main() {
  std::cout << "Value: " << VALUE << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Все работает норм.

Comment: уточню. Это же работает и в gcc. Тут ключевое слово - линукс.

Comment: Скорее, наверное -  *nix)